# Hide tooltip with message "This is a required field" of an input tag in HTML

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am working on some forms with angular material.
All the required messages are attached to the input elements and they're coming from angular material with immediate validation when the user types inside the input.
The problem is on IE11, when you focus on the required input element and you start typing, the tooltip with the required message("This is a required field") is appeared and it is constantly blinking while you're typing which is annoying for the user.

Is it any way to hide the tooltip with css, like display: none?
It is impossible to debug the error on IE11 . So it would be helpful if someone could provide a method to target the tooltip with css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set the `novalidate` flag on your form: `<form novalidate>`

Comment: there is no way to target the tooltip with css?

Comment: No it is a browser-native implementation. You can use the `novalidate` flag and do the tooltips yourself. Probably `angular-material` also includes this.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `<form novalidate>`, you should remove `required` attribute in the form input.

```
<input name="myName" ng-model="myName" required>
```

remove required in the above line.

Comment: But I asked if we can target the tooltip in css and not exclude the required attribute..

Comment: Then it is enough to add novalidate in form tag. For reference, you can visit [link](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/11-novalidate.html?num=5)